# Upload to firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, upload, firebase-storage

Good night, I have a simple question. How to upload a file to firebase storage? I accessed the tutorial, but I did not quite understand. Could you show me an algorithm that sends a file to firebase storage? I am learning now. in node.js

Comment: Hi Renan, please share with us what have you tried already. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you create a client-server on your nodejs program and make requests to the firebase-storage. You have the follow the rules (headers) that firebase-storage requires.